# problems on Brouwer's fixed point theorem

Tags: general-topology

Find a map $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that $f$ have no fixed point, where $S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2<1\}$ is the open unit ball. This implies $S$ is not homeomorphic to the closed unit ball. Can anyone help?

Comment: Find a homeomorphism $S\cong(0,1)\times(0,1)$, then an automorphism on that space without a fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

For any convex set $U$ whose boundary $B$ is not a subset of $U$, you can pick any point $p \in B-U$ and define $f$ as the map that takes each point $x$ half-way to $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it for the open interval $(0,1)$ first. You should quickly find that $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$ works nicely. As $(-1,1)$ is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$ we can find a map $\phi\colon (-1,1)\to (-1,1)$ without a fixed point too. Now let $p\colon S\to S$ be projection onto the first factor and let $f\colon S\to S$ be given by $f=(\phi,\mbox{Id}_{\mathbb{R}})\circ p\colon (x,y)\mapsto(\phi(x),0)$. As $\phi$ has no fixed points, so too does $f$.